# Only one command executes in for-loop in bat file

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I try to write a bat-script that will copy all the files from source directory to destination. Also there must be a few seconds delay between each iteration.

```
for %%i in (%source%) do (
copy "%%i" "%destination%" 
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 3 -w 3000 > nul
)
```

But I have a problem. Looks like this piece of code executes only the Copy command, but I need both `Copy` and `Ping` for each iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: Why do you think PING is not executing? Have you removed the `>nul` and proven it?

Comment: How is source defined? I'm wondering if perhaps you want `(%source%\*)`.

Comment: source defined as "C:\Tickets\". %source%* in my for-loop helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, ping executed, but only once.

Second, construction %source%* instead of %source% in my for-loop is the right solution